# Need help to pass custom user data to insert function at azure mobile service

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, azure-mobile-services, phonegap-pushplugin

I am working on cordova hybrid app with azure mobile services.I want to send push notifications only to specific users.I want to pass custom user data to insert function at azure mobile services.

> > function insert(item, user, request) {  //here need user obj with
> >     custom properties
> >
> > }

Secondly i don't understand syntax of template registration

> var template = "{ \"data\" : {\"message\":\"$(message)\"}}";

what it do?
 how do we modify it?

Comment: Anybody here? Plz help!!

Comment: What kind of extra data do you need?  There isn't a way to customize the user object to have it, but you can call out to another table to fetch it, or pass it up as extra data on the item or request objects.  For templates, take a look at the Notification Hub documentation on Azure.

Comment: Thanks phillipv for your suggestion.